Will the ansi.sys driver work in the DOS box emulator?
Even better, is there a way to make the driver work in the windows 11 command line window?

DOSBox has built-in support for “ANSI” escape sequences. See also DOS: How do I type an ANSI escape sequence?
The Windows command-line window also supports ANSI escape sequences, by default since version 1909, or with some configuration since version 1511; see Windows console with ANSI colors handling.

Woh! That's a really complete answer; thanx!!

While it may answer what you wanted to know, it does not answer the asked question though.

Right, this doesn’t answer the titular question — I can’t check right now. In any case DOSBox can’t load device drivers directly, you’d have to use a tool such as DEVLOAD, or use another implementation provided as a .COM file.
